# Find the maximum number of consecutive times value in array is less than threshold

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following numpy array
`array([0.66594665, 0.33003433, NaN, 0.42567293, 0.48161913, 0.30000838, 0.13639367, 0.84300475, 0.19029748, NaN])`

I would like to find the number of consecutive times the values in the array are less than 0.5. Is there a way to do this without using a for loop? In this example, the answer is 4 for the following sub-sequence: `0.42567293, 0.48161913, 0.30000838, 0.13639367`

Comment: Can you share your attempt. Minimal reproducible example

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np

# Create a numpy array
arr = np.array([0.66594665, 0.33003433, np.nan, 0.42567293, 0.48161913, 0.30000838, 0.13639367, 0.84300475, 0.19029748, np.nan])

# Create a numpy array with consecutive values less than 0.5
arr_less_than_0_5 = np.where(arr < 0.5)[0]

# Print the array
print(arr_less_than_0_5)

# Get the number of consecutive times the values in a numpy array are less than 0.5
print(len(arr_less_than_0_5))
```

The question was to give the number of consecutive times the values are less than 0.5.
It was not asked to print the specific values.

So this answers your question

Comment: Did you run before post? It will show NaN error

Comment: This also does not show strictly *consecutive* elements. It will just show all indices that are < 0.5

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.